# how to sequence varying function calls with promises with a queue

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have a function that returns a promise

```
function ajax() { sideeffect(); return new Promise() }
```

I call this function at various times, what I want is this function to queue the calls and only run after the previous call is resolved.

If I call `ajax` three times in a row `ajax(); ajax(); ajax()` I want this to be
`ajax.then(ajax).then(ajax)` or if i call four times it chains accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a persistent variable representing the last Promise created, chain onto it when `ajax` is called, reassign the persistent variable to the new chain, and return the new chain:

```js
let lastProm = Promise.resolve();
function ajax(ms) {
  // sideeffect();
  lastProm = lastProm.then(() => (
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
  ));
  return lastProm;
}

ajax(1000).then(() => console.log('resolved 1'));
ajax(1000).then(() => console.log('resolved 2'));
ajax(3000).then(() => console.log('resolved 3'));
ajax(1000).then(() => console.log('resolved 4'));
```